# How to produce a table of three inputs to reach a given output? (Excel model)

Tags: excel, datatable, combinations

I have a very detailed excel model to calculate the profitability of a project, that we can call *P*.

The model has been simplified to compute from 3 unrelated variables. I would like to automatically create a table that shows how inputs *A*, *B* and *C* might vary in order to produce a pre-defined level of profitability, *P*. For instance, if *A* = 4 & *B* = 30, then *C* must = 2 in order for *P* to equal 20%. Likewise, if *A* = 5 & *B* = 25, then *C* must = 3 in order for *P* to equal 20%. *A* and *B* should be tested at sensible increments, perhaps 8 intervals each.

A laborious (not scalable) equivalent would be to manually define *A* and *B*, then goal-seek *C* to our pre-defined level of *P* - we'd then repeat for each combination of *A* and *B* at the given intervals and record in a two-way table.

I believe a conventional two-way data table would be pratical if the model sitting behind the inputs were greatly simplified, unfortunately this isn't possible.

Thanks to anyone that can lend a hand. Kind regards.

Comment: Please, if down-voting, let me know why. I've searched thoroughly for the answer so if I'm being too vague, please let me know where I can be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this will be with a VBA macro and the prebuilt `GoalSeek` Function something like this (p is in cell D1) :

```
Range(”D1”).GoalSeek Goal:=20 _
ChangingCell:=Range(“C1”)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Richard - looks like my first bit of VBA is on the way!